# How to add a btrfs raid 1 to an encrypted lvm2 volume group under Solus OS (Linux)?

Tags: linux, lvm, btrfs, luks

What I have:

Solus OS install with an encrypted LVM2 on a 56G SSD w/o swap - works pretty
good. I have 32G RAM, so swap isn't an issue right now - it's my future main rig
and it is mainly intended to being used as desktop for office, web, daw and
rust programming (not everything at the same time).

What I want to do:

Add two 1T hds formatted with btrfs in a raid 1 configuration to the actual lvm2
volume group and they should contain /home (with all the stuff that's being
already there) and being mounted as /home during boot so that I'll have 1T space
for /home with software mirroring. The raid level 1 has to be for data and
metadata.

/home should stay encrypted with the already used key phrase.
Also I'd like to mount the btrfs' with -o compression-force that has to be done
in fstab and fscrypt. I'm currently unsure whether it was fscrypt or something
else sounding similar.

What I've understood so far:

1. create the btrfs raid
2. copy everything from /home to the temporary mounted /home-btrfs
3. do some magic to get: /home on ssd gone, unmount /home-btrfs add btrfs-raid
   to the volume group and mount the btrfs-raid as /home - everything is
   encrypted again, but with more space

Is there anybody who can explain it to me? I'm unsure that I understood it
well enough to get started. I am not afraid of the terminal or any cli.
I've just decided to opt out of the vendor lock-in of Windows 10 and go for
Linux. And I know that I'll get some performance hits with that config but that
is okay for me.

My plan is currently to do this:

1. gparted will create a partition table (gpt) and format /dev/sdb1 with btrfs
2. open the terminal/shell
3. sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /home-btrfs
4. copy everything frome /home to /home-btrfs with cp -var /home /home-btrfs
5. gparted will create a partition table (gpt) on /dev/sdc -> /dev/sdc1
6. btrfs device add /dev/sdc1 /home-btrfs
7. btrfs fi balance start -mconvert=raid1,soft -dconvert=raid1,soft /home-btrfs
8. open a second shell to watch the raid conversion progress
9. btrfs filesystem balance status /home-btrfs
10. btrfs balance start -dusage=0 -musage=0 /mnt/btrfs (get rid of empty chunks)
11. I'm stucked because now I could not get to fit lvextend, pvcreate, vgextend
    and other things from lvm2 into my plan.

I apologize my bad grammar.

Comment: I think this would be a much better question for https://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: Didn't know that one. Thanks for hinting.